# Using XmlReader how do I restart at the beginning?

Tags: c#, xml

This is really a 2 part question...

1. I have a XmlReader object I have created from a memory stream.  I have used the .Read() method a few times and now I want to go back to the beginning and start over at the declaration node.  How can I do that?
2. When creating the XmlReader object I create a XmlDocument object and a MemoryStream object.  Do these objects need to be destroyed somehow after creating the XmlReader with the memory stream?  Or would destroying them also effect the XmlReader object?

**This is how I create the XmlReader object**

```
XmlReader xmlReader = null;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(m_sXMLPath);

if (doc.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
{
    XmlDeclaration dec = null;
    byte[] bytes = null;
    MemoryStream ms = null;

    dec = (XmlDeclaration)doc.FirstChild;
    switch (dec.Encoding.ToLower())
    {
        case "utf-8":
            bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(m_sXMLPath));
            break;
        case "utf-16":
            bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(m_sXMLPath));
            break;
        default:
            throw new XmlException("");
    }

    if (bytes != null)
    {
        ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(ms);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot restart your `XmlReader` object to the beginning.  As per Microsoft's documentation:

> XmlReader provides forward-only, read-only access to a stream of XML data. The XmlReader class conforms to the W3C Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 and the Namespaces in XML recommendations.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlReader.aspx

If for some reason you really do need to go back to the beginning, instead you should use your `XmlReader` to load a `XDocument` object.  You can then use the `XDocument` object to query any part of your XML.  In addition, you should wrap your Stream based objects in a `using` block so you don't need to worry about destruction.  Example below:

```
XDocument myXmlDoc;
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
     using(XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(ms))
     {
           myXmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);

           //query your XDocument here to your heart's desire here in any order you want
      }
 }
```

In case you aren't familar with LINQ to XML take a look at the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

If you don't want to use `XDocument` and stick to `XmlDocument` you can also use that (without queries) to re-traverse your XML document.  Either way though you do not need to dispose of a `XmlDocument` (or `XDocument`) when you are done with it since it's not a disposable object.

Comment: So to answer my 2nd question, I do NOT need to do anything with the XmlDocument but DO need to do something with the MemoryStream correct?  If I wrap it up in a using statement and created a XmlReader object in the using statement would the XmlReader object still be ok when referenced outside of the using statement?

Comment: @ArvoBowen Correct.  But as @JohnSaunders mentioned you really don't need to use a `MemoryStream` either.  Just open a TextStream to your XML file, and pass the TextStream to the `XDocument.Load(stream)` or `XmlDocument.Load(stream)` function.  This load should be within a using block.  As usual with scopes you cannot reference the stream outside of the block, however you won't need to since your `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` now contains the entirety of your XML.

Comment: If you don't want to create XDocuments or XElements, you can use MoveToElement() in combo with reader.ReadSubtree() to keep reading the xml over and over again. If you start at the top element, this can be the entire xml string. I just pass each reader.ReadSubtree() to a method that ensures its disposal once I'm done with it.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're using XmlReader makes no sense. Once you have the data loaded into the `XmlDocument` (`XDocument` would be better), there's no sense in using an `XmlReader`.

In .NET, it is not generally necessary to destroy objects after use - that's what the garbage collector is for.

Comment: Although you are absolute correct in that objects do not generally need to be destroyed due to garbage collection, he does ask about the `MemoryStream` and `XmlReader` objects.  It is best practice to at least call `.Close()` after use or better yet wrap in a `using` or try,catch,finally structure when using `IDisposable` objects or streams.

Comment: @JNYRanger: yes, but if he makes his code sensible, it will be using neither XmlReader nor MemoryStream, so `using` will not apply, which is why I didn't mention it (contrary to my usual practice).

Comment: Touche.  He'll need to use a stream at some point I figured to initially read the XML data, so that's why I mentioned it.